# Não contar em duplicidade os inteiros 1 e 0 quando estes estiverem acima, abaixo ou ao lado de um inteiro 2?

Tags: coordenadas

Este código conta quantos setores ferteis (1) e inferteis (0) estão cobertos por pelo menos um irrigador (2). A matriz `a[m][n]` representa um terreno com irrigadores (2), terras ferteis (1) e terras inferteis:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int m, n, i, j, dx, dy, qtdFertil, qtdInfertil;
    int a[10][10];
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
/*ex. de entradas:
4 6
0 0 0 1 1 0
0 2 2 1 1 0
1 0 2 1 2 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
4 5
Obs.: a saida deveria ser 4 e 5 mas está saindo 5 7
*/
    //leitura da matriz
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {       //varre as linhas m
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {   //varre as colunas n
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //calcula setores ferteis/inferteis irrigados
    qtdFertil = 0;
    qtdInfertil = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < m-1; i++) {              //varre as linhas da matriz Aij
        for (j = 1; j < n-1; j++) {         //varre as colunas da matriz Aij
            if (a[i][j] == 2){
                if(a[i-1][j] == 1) {        //elemento a norte de aij
                    qtdFertil++; }
                if(a[i-1][j] == 0) {
                    qtdInfertil++; }
                if(a[i+1][j] == 1) {        //elemento a sul de aij
                    qtdFertil++; }
                if(a[i+1][j] == 0) {
                    qtdInfertil++; }
                if(a[i][j+1] == 1) {        //elemento a leste de aij
                    qtdFertil++; }
                if(a[i][j+1] == 0) {
                    qtdInfertil++; }
                if(a[i][j-1] == 1) {        //elemento a oeste de aij
                    qtdFertil++; }
                if(a[i][j-1] == 0) {
                    qtdInfertil++; }
            }else{
                continue;   //passa para a próxima iteração
            }
        }
    }
    //escreve a quantidade de setires ferteis e inferteis cobertos
    //por pelo menos um irrigador
    printf("%d %d\n", qtdFertil, qtdInfertil);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu programa está certo, a menos que não se possa contar os mesmos setores mais de uma vez,

## Setores com zeros

```
  0 0     
0 2 2      
  0 2   2 0
        0
```

Se você contar as ocorrências no mapa em destaque para os zeros, verá que terão 7 ocorrências.

## Setores com uns

```
(linha faltante)
    2 1 1  
    2 1 2  
    1
```

Verá que tem 5 ocorrências de uns.

Para que não ocorra isso, você pode ir substituindo os valores já levados em consideração, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define JACONTADO  3
#define IRRIGADOR  2
#define FERTIL     1
#define INFERTIL   0

int main()
{
    int m, n, i, j, dx, dy, contagem[4];
    int a[10][10];
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

    for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }

    contagem[INFERTIL] = 0;
    contagem[FERTIL] = 0;
    contagem[IRRIGADOR] = 0;
    contagem[JACONTADO] = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < m - 1; ++i)
        for (j = 1; j < n - 1; ++j)
        {
            if (a[i][j] == IRRIGADOR)
            {
                // Norte.
                ++contagem[a[i - 1][j]];
                // Sul.
                ++contagem[a[i + 1][j]];
                // Leste.
                ++contagem[a[i][j + 1]];
                // Oeste.
                ++contagem[a[i][j - 1]];

                // Substituicao dos setores ja contados.
                a[i - 1][j] = a[i - 1][j] == IRRIGADOR ? IRRIGADOR : JACONTADO;
                a[i + 1][j] = a[i + 1][j] == IRRIGADOR ? IRRIGADOR : JACONTADO;
                a[i][j - 1] = a[i][j - 1] == IRRIGADOR ? IRRIGADOR : JACONTADO;
                a[i][j + 1] = a[i][j + 1] == IRRIGADOR ? IRRIGADOR : JACONTADO;
            }
        }

    printf("%d %d", contagem[FERTIL], contagem[INFERTIL]);

    return 0;
}
```